# how to reference an autogenerated id in firestore collection

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to update a 'progress' field in the document with autogenerated id (using fire store)every time the progress button is clicked.
[image]

I tried in several different ways but nothing seems to be working. I am attaching my method:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    var email = user.email;
    var documentID = database.collection("ChosenChallenge").doc().id;

    database
    .collection("Users")
    .doc(email)
    .collection("ChosenChallenge")
    .doc(documentID)
    .update({
        Progress: percentRange
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log('added!');
  });
    }, )
```

and the class:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import './newprogressbar.css';
import { firebaseAppAuth, database } from "../firebase";
import firebase from "firebase/app";



export const ProgressBarContainer = (props) => {

let [percentRange, setProgress] = useState(0);


const handleUpdate = () => {
    setProgress(percentRange < 99 ? percentRange + 7.14285714 : 100);
    props.onChange(percentRange + 7.14285714);
}

const Range = (props) => {
    return (
        <div className="range" style={{width: `${props.percentRange}%`}}/>
    );
};

const ProgressBar = (props) => {
    return (
        <div className="progress-bar">
            <Range percentRange={props.percentRange}/>
        </div>
    );
};

useEffect(() => {
    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    var email = user.email;
    var documentID = database.collection("ChosenChallenge").doc().id;

    database
    .collection("Users")
    .doc(email)
    .collection("ChosenChallenge")
    .doc(documentID)
    .update({
        Progress: percentRange
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log('added!');
  });
    }, )


    return (
        <div id="progresscontainer">
            <ProgressBar percentRange={percentRange} />
            <button id="updatepic" onClick={handleUpdate}>Daily Update</button>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Any help high appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

`database.collection("ChosenChallenge").doc().id` generates a new random document ID every time it's called.  It doesn't know which existing document you want.

If you want to update a document, you must know its existing ID.  There is no avoiding that.  If you don't know the ID, you will need to [query the collection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) to find the document ID based on something you know about the contents of the document.

If you don't know the ID and you don't know anything about the contents of the document to filter a query, you're stuck, and you might need to rethink how you are using Firestore for this app.